# How to get Get Unsettled Transaction List from authoriz.net?

Tags: node.js, authorize.net

[image]

the above image shows list of unsettled transaction in authorize.net UI. When I request by the `getUnsettledTransactionList` API call I am receiving the empty result set, why?

```
 "response": {
        "messages": {
            "resultCode": "Ok",
            "message": [
                {
                    "code": "I00004",
                    "text": "No records found."
                }
            ]
        },
        "totalNumInResultSet": 0
    }
```

I am using a sandbox account in Authorize.net and NodeJs for development based on following code

https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#transaction-reporting-get-unsettled-transaction-list

here is my code

```
function getUnsettledTransactionList() {

    var merchantAuthenticationType = new ApiContracts.MerchantAuthenticationType();
    merchantAuthenticationType.setName( process.env.SERVICE_CREDITCARD_API_APILOGINKEY );
    merchantAuthenticationType.setTransactionKey( process.env.SERVICE_CREDITCARD_API_TRANSACTIONKEY );

    var getRequest = new ApiContracts.GetUnsettledTransactionListRequest();

    getRequest.setMerchantAuthentication(merchantAuthenticationType);
    getRequest.setStatus(ApiContracts.TransactionGroupStatusEnum.PENDINGAPPROVAL);

    //keeping promise resolve and reject funcs outside the promise scope
    var promiseResolve, promiseReject;

    var promise = new Promise( (_resolve, _reject)=>{
        promiseResolve = _resolve;
        promiseReject = _reject;
    });

    var ctrl = new ApiControllers.GetUnsettledTransactionListController(getRequest.getJSON());

    ctrl.execute(function(){

        var apiResponse = ctrl.getResponse();
        var response = new ApiContracts.GetUnsettledTransactionListResponse(apiResponse);

        if(response != null){
            if(response.getMessages().getResultCode() == ApiContracts.MessageTypeEnum.OK){

                var result = { 
                    message: response.getMessages().getMessage()[0].getText(),
                    messageCode: response.getMessages().getMessage()[0].getCode(),
                    transactions: [],
                    status: true,
                    response: response
                }

                if(response.getTransactions() != null)
                    result.transactions = response.getTransactions().getTransaction();                

                promiseResolve( result );
            }
            else{
                promiseReject({
                    resultCode: response.getMessages().getResultCode(),
                    errorCode: response.getMessages().getMessage()[0].getCode(),
                    errorMessage: response.getMessages().getMessage()[0].getText(),
                    status: false,
                    response: response
                });
            }
        }
        else{
            promiseReject( { message: 'Null Response.', status: false } );
        }

    });

    return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to set the Status for the transactions, remove this line of code.

```
    getRequest.setStatus(ApiContracts.TransactionGroupStatusEnum.PENDINGAPPROVAL);
```

If you add this field in your request, you get only transaction which are pending for approval, and you might be having no transaction pending for approval thus you are getting an empty list.

Comment: thank you, How can I get `Captured/Pending Settlement` only?

Comment: I don't think you can just get those transactions with `Captured/Pending Settlement` status, you will get all the unsettled transactions and with every transaction you will get `transactionStatus` using which you can filter those.